# Google maps data mashup for private data?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

Google maps/earth has a nice mashup [tool](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/spreadsheet3.html). But it isn't for private data.

Is there a mashup tool for mapping **private** data onto Google/Bing/etc maps?

Answer (score 0):

[www.umapper.com](http://www.umapper.com/) combined with [openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) might be an answer.

**Added** It looks like the umapper.com service can be used to import data relatively easily to a mapping system. And they make reference to "private maps" which is what I want. Their import isn't documented yet, I have asked them for more info about it.

umapper apparently works with Bing, Google, and OpenStreetMap. The latter is important since it offers the most liberal licensing for private use. With the others you need to license them for private use ($$$).

Comment: Can you explain these links so that we know that they refer to?